# How can we use EEG data to predict urge of smoking?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience

I am from Computer Sciences background. The problem which I want to target is to be able to successfully predict (to a degree) that a person is going to smoke in near future.

I have a brainwave sensor which gives me EEG. I am interested in using this data to predict the urge of smoking. My questions are as follows:

- Is is possible to do such kind of analysis? If yes, what are the key terms I should explore to understand the relation between EEG values and urge of smoking.
- If no, what should be the data which I should try to get to solve this problem?

I do not seek complete answer, I only seek pointers to helpful literature.

Comment: @ChrisStronks: Thank you for your inputs Chris. I have updated the question description. By behavioral analysis, I mean indications through body language, social interactions, cellphone usage, internet usage, etc. In brain activity, I would limit myself to EEG data. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. However, the body of your question reads pretty much like: "How to predict one lighting a ciggie from EEG" while your title emphasizes behavioral analysis. sorry for being picky, but broad, vaguely defined questions tend to remain unanswered, while well- defined questions generally get helpful and multiple to-the-point answers - I'm just trying to help!

Comment: @ChrisStronks: Absolutely true. I am thinking of a better title for the question. :)

Comment: @ChrisStronks: Thank you Chris. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time Chris. I have separated the questions. The other one is here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9111/how-can-we-analyse-user-behavior-to-predict-urge-of-smoking

Comment: @Bhoot, I think [this answer](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/6556/2926) should get you started.  Most of the work involved will be in feature selection/engineering, and that's a very open-ended, trial-and-error-driven process.