# How can we analyse user behavior to predict urge of smoking?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience

The problem which I want to target is to be able to successfully predict (to a degree) that a person is going to smoke in near future.

I want to look at the relationship between chemical reactions in the body, user behavior and urge for smoking. My questions are as follows:

- What happens inside the body which makes the user feel an urge to smoke. By this, I mean are there specific 'chemicals' which are released in the body? Can we measure it?
- Is there a relation between user behavior and urge of smoking? If yes, please help me understand it or point me towards literature which supports the same.

Please point me towards (even remotely relevant) literature which can help me in finding answers to some of these questions.